# Emacs: define custom hook on a command

Tags: emacs, hook

Is there a way to hook onto command A, so that B is always called after A executes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the most straight-forward way to accomplish this is through the use of [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).
You would do something along the lines of:

```
(defadvice command-A (after b-after-a activate)
  "Call command-B after command-A"
  (command-B))
```

This approach has the advantage that it works even when command-A is redefined.  It does not, however, work on macros or on primitive functions called from the C code.  But, in practice the thought of advising those functions is rare.

That said, it might be worth looking into just defining a new command (`command-C`) which first calls `command-A` and then `command-B`.

You could also play around with [symbol function indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html) and writing a new command.

It kind of depends on what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Is it also possible to "give advice" before the function called evaluates?

Comment: @Dualinity Yes, you replace `after` in the definition with `before` (or `around`).  Though if it is really a command (it uses `interactive`) and you want to change how the interactive part works, then you need to ensure your advice has `interactive` - check out the link to advice for more details.  And check out the "tutorial" that is in the comments in the advice library itself (`M-x find-library advice RET`)

Answer (score 3):

You can advice a function using defadvice:

```
;; This is the original function command-A
(defun command-A () (do-it))

;; This call will cause (do-sometihng-after-command-A) to be called 
;; every-time (command-A) is called.
(defadvice command-A (after after-command-A)
    (do-something-after-command-A))

;; Enable the advice defined above
(ad-activate 'command-A)
```

See the info node (elisp)Advising Functions for more information and examples.